# Дублирование имен файлов в проектах С++

Tags: c++, qtcreator, gdb

Имею проект C++ под **qmake** с иерархической структурой **TEMPLATE=SUBDIRS**

```
Module1
   ModuleStaticLib1
   UnutTest1
Module2
   ModuleStaticLib2
   UnutTest2
Module3
   Приложение
```

В каждом подпроекте могут быть *.cpp файлы с одинаковыми именами

- Module1/ModuleStaticLib1/Controller.cpp - *реализация класса namespace Module1::Controller*
- UnitTest1/Controller.cpp - *юнит тест класса Module1::Controller*
- Module2/ModuleStaticLib2/Controller.cpp - *реализация Module2::Controller*
- UnitTest2/Controller.cpp - *юнит тест класса Module2::Controller*

Работаю в qtcreator. Обратил внимание на странный баг при отладке, если установить точку останова в  UnitTest1/Controller.cpp, она ставится также и в Module1/ModuleStaticLib1/Controller.cpp (может и в другие одноименные файлы, но я гоняю один тест). В рамках одного модуля имена файлов не повторяются.

Кроме того мой коллега, выразил сомнение в таком подходе, могут быть  проблемы со сборкой(я не замечал). На сколько корректно использование одинаковых имен в разных модулях, и чем может быть баг с точками оcтанова qtcreator или GDB?

- QtCreator 3.5.81
- gcc version 4.8.4
- GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
- Linux Mint17

PS Демонстрация структуры "Глюкодрома" =)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

По-моему, опция "Set breakpoints using a full absolute path" решает проблему с дублированием точек останова.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Будет жуткий глюкодром - среда объединяет файлы с равными именами.

Но гораздо хуже будет глюкодром в сознании человека, которому вы этой лазанье придется разбираться. Хотя бы из-за этого стоит уйти от такой структуры.

UPD от 9 октября 2016.

Qt creator  в связке с MSVC2012 работает как попало, если в проекте есть одинаковые по именам файлы, он затирает одни объектники (*.obj) другими, более поздними, так как сваливает все в один каталог. В итоге - тонны ошибок при линковке.

Comment: Вот уж сознанию человека одинаковые имена обычно не мешают.

Comment: Первое утверждение лишь подтверждает общую неспособность QtCreator работать с различными проектами — как была недо-IDE, так и осталась. Второе утверждение весьма спорно.

Comment: Поясните  "глюкодром", за исключением чехарды с точками останова, не наблюдаю проблем. QtCreator не идеальная среда, но лучше для моих задач увы я не нашел.

Comment: Что значит среда объединяет файлы?

Comment: @pier_nasos - среда рассматривает файлы с одинаковым именем как один и тот же. Это может вносить путаницу в рабочий процесс.

Comment: Есть все же один баг, к котороому я привык(забыл его упомянуть). По F4 переключение между хидером и исходником, кидает меня на тесты.

Comment: Кстати перешел на именование файлов юнит тестов в нижнем регистре(решило проблему переключения cpp|h), кроме того забыл упомянуть, что в каждом подпроекте переопределяется переменая QMAKE OBJECTS_DIR, что решает упомянутую проблему с затиранием объектников(В рамках одного проекта)